# Importing data from another open Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook(workbookA) which contains data extracted from 10 other workbooks, each line has a column identifying from which workbook they came from.

The problem is that, in some columns of workbookA, the values are incorrect and need to be re-imported

I know how to do loops and set values in VBA, just now how to work with 2 workbooks at the same time

So, for each cell in workbookA, i would find its match from the reference workbook, through a UID, and then replace the value in workbookA

If its possible for it to open the workbook too, that would be even better, automate the whole process

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.google.com/#q=open+workbook+vba+stackoverflow

Comment: why not simply using cross-workbooks connections: in any relevant cell of workbookA you want to type `='[workbookN]sheetM'!B14`. you set it once and it'll keep the wanted connection for ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague to give a specific answer, but some general pointers:

1. Yes, it is possible open two workbooks at the same time. You will want to add a macro module to WorkbookA.
2. Use a for loop to loop over the column headings. Append the path where these files can be found and open using [Workbooks.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx). That will return a reference to the second workbook you can dig into for your data.
3. Use ThisWorkbook to refer to WorkbookA.
4. Use [.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839657.aspx) to close each workbook when you are done.

Comment: Thanks! That's all I needed to know